# If(AND) combination produces “You've entered too many arguments for this function” error

Tags: microsoft-excel

I am struggling to find the missing piece to a formula based on two dropdowns with both having the ability to include all the criteria. Can some evaluate this for me?

```
=if(and(D6="All",D8="All"),sumifs(GL!$P:$P,GL!$I:$I,D$15,GL!$AB:$AB,$B17),if(D6=All,sumifs(GL!$P:$P,GL!$I:$I,D$15,GL!$AB:$AB,$B17, GL!$R:$R, $D$8)), if(D8=All,sumifs(GL!$P:$P,GL!$I:$I,D$15,GL!$AB:$AB,$B17, GL!$A:$A,$D$6)),sumifs(GL!$P:$P,GL!$I:$I,D$15,GL!$AB:$AB,$B17, GL!$A:$A, $D$6,GL!$R:$R,$D$8))
```

Answer (score 0):

we can shorten it by putting the IF in the SUMIFS and using `"*"` to return all:

```
=SUMIFS(GL!$P:$P,GL!$I:$I,D$15,GL!$AB:$AB,$B17, GL!$A:$A, IF($D$6="All","*",$D$6),GL!$R:$R,IF($D$8="All","*",$D$8))
```

---

As to why yours returns the error, you have `)` out of place:

```
=IF(AND(D6="All",D8="All"),SUMIFS(GL!$P:$P,GL!$I:$I,D$15,GL!$AB:$AB,$B17),IF(D6=All,SUMIFS(GL!$P:$P,GL!$I:$I,D$15,GL!$AB:$AB,$B17, GL!$R:$R, $D$8), IF(D8=All,SUMIFS(GL!$P:$P,GL!$I:$I,D$15,GL!$AB:$AB,$B17, GL!$A:$A,$D$6),SUMIFS(GL!$P:$P,GL!$I:$I,D$15,GL!$AB:$AB,$B17, GL!$A:$A, $D$6,GL!$R:$R,$D$8))))
```

Comment: Stunning Scott! Your contribution has saved me from a ton of headache. Thank you again :)